# PHP CURL funcion is not working for google timezone api

Tags: php, google-maps, curl

Php curl functions get nothing from google timezone api..

```
<?php

$url='https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/timezone/json?location=39.6034810,-119.6822510&timestamp=1331161200&sensor=false';

$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,  $url);                   
$dta = curl_exec($ch);                  

curl_close($ch);
print_r( $dta);
?>
```

`print_r( $dta);` prints nothing.

But when i access the url https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/timezone/json?location=39.6034810,-119.6822510&timestamp=1331161200&sensor=false

It gives the result.

How should I retrieve content from the link? Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

There is no error but what google say you

Please check curl error and solve it

```
<?php
    $url='https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/timezone/json?location=39.6034810,-119.6822510&timestamp=1331161200&sensor=false';
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    print_r($data);
    if(curl_errno($ch))  echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);  
?>
```

Comment: i'm having the below error :  Curl error: SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed..        what is the problem in that?

Comment: use this code it's solve your problem
`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);`